# PHP: Extract word from string and get word count

Tags: php, string

I have tried for hours to figure this out, to no avail. I have searched and searched, with a lot of results saying to use an array. I can not use an array as this has not been covered in my class yet. Here is what I am to do:
I am to use a for loop to examine the characters using index variable.
When a blank character is found, this indicated the end of the word.
I then need to extract the word from the string and increment the word count, thus printing the word count and extracted word, continuing til the end of the sentence.
Then printing the total word count.
What I am stuck on is extracting the word. Here is what I have so far, which could very well be wrong but I am at my wits end here, so any little bit of push in the right direction would be great.
(Remember, I can not use arrays.)

```
$stringSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$wordcount = 1;
$blankCharacter = stripos($stringSentence, " ");

for ($i =0; $i<strlen($stringSentence);$i++)
{
     $i. " ". $stringSentence{$i}."<br>";

}
if ($blankCharacter)
{
    echo $wordcount++, " ";
    echo substr($stringSentence,0,$blankCharacter);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: `stripos()` will only find the first occurrence of that string, so your loop only happens 1 time.

Comment: Expected Output:

1 The
2 quick
3 brown
4 fox
5 jumps
6 over
7 the 
8 lazy
9 dog

There are 9 words in this sentence.

Comment: You probably have to use a loop, to learn how it works, but `strtok()` would have been a good function to use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered just going through each individual letter to check for spaces and storing in a temporary buffer otherwise? One example:

```
$stringSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

$buffer = '';
$count = 1;
$length = strlen($stringSentence);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if ($stringSentence{$i} !== ' ') {
        $buffer .= $stringSentence{$i};
    } else {
        echo $count++ . ' ' . $buffer . ' ';
        $buffer = '';
    }
}
echo $count . ' ' . $buffer;
```

I'm not putting much explanation into my answer.. sort of a backwards approach of giving you the answer but it's up to you to understand how and why the above approach works.

Comment: Generally people asking for help on their homework should have an answer just thrust in their lap or they will never learn.

Comment: @webternals Which is why homework questions shouldn't really be asked on SO - because this is what they're going to get. I don't have the time to write pseudocode or paragraphs of theory or hints, especially since it doesn't make it a "real answer." There's a lot of challenging code in my answer that OP would have to wrap their head around and defend if they were to copy-paste it to their teacher.

Comment: First, I would just like to note that posting my question was a last resort after I have went over every single book that we have to read and every note and video we have watched thus far. I do not expect the answer handed to me, as I am one that actually likes to understand why I am writing code, and how it worked. This will be my career so to no understand would be just throwing myself under the bus. 
Secondly, @sjagr I originally had each character numbered including spaces. hence the $i. " ".$string{i}." "; I later added the if statement after other research.

Comment: @TiffanyCox Review my code more carefully please so you better understand the approach - it's not printing character numbers but word numbers, and if you run it you'll see you get your desired output. Would you like annotations in the code?

Comment: @sjagr, I noticed it after I commented on it. We didn't go over the operators to much and with the way this class is set up its hard to get complete understanding. There is a choice of learning C++, Java, or Web Development. Professor teaches in C so I get confused when I try to complete assignments,as I am the only one learning the Web Development aspect. I appreciate your help very kindly, seems as though I was headed in the right direction in the beginning, just didn't  quite make it there. Again, thank you!

Comment: @TiffanyCox It suddenly makes more sense why you were given this challenge. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays aren't that complicated! And a solution is very easy with it:

(Here I just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string into an array. Then I simply loop through the array and print the output)

```
<?php

    $stringSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    $words = explode(" ", $stringSentence);

    foreach($words as $k => $v)
        echo "WordCount: " . ($k+1) . "| Word: $v<br>";

    echo "Total WordCount: " . count($words);

?>
```

output:

```
WordCount: 1| Word: The
//...
WordCount: 9| Word: dog
Total WordCount: 9
```

If you want to read more about arrays see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

**EDIT:**

If you can't use arrays, just use this:

Here I just loop through all characters of the sentence to check if it is either a space OR the end of the string. If the condition is true I print the word count + the substr from the last space until the current one. Then I also increment the word count with 1. At the end I simply print the total word count (note that I subtracted 1, because the last word will also add 1 to the count which is too much).

```
<?php

    $stringSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    $wordcount = 1;
    $blankCharacter = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($stringSentence); $i++) {
        if($stringSentence[$i] == " " || $i+1 == strlen($stringSentence)) {
            echo "WordCount: $wordcount | Word: " . substr($stringSentence, $blankCharacter, $i-$blankCharacter+1) . "<br>";
            $blankCharacter = $i;
            $wordcount++;
        }

    }
    echo "Total WordCount: " . ($wordcount-1);

?>
```

Comment: I think not using array is more a constraint of the problem, not the OPs understanding

Comment: The OP cannot use an array because it hasn't been covered in class yet.

Comment: I understand they are not complicated, just can't use them.

Comment: @TiffanyCox it's funny because a string is an array of chars

Answer (score 0):

Since this is home work I can't do it for you but you have an end bracket for one in the wrong place

Have a look at this sudo code and you should be in the right direction.

```
$blankCharacter = ' ';
for ($i =0; $i<strlen($stringSentence);$i++)
{         
    if (thisCharacter == $blankCharacter)
    {
        $wordcount++;
    }
}
```